# Dynamic programming solution to maximizing an expression by placing parentheses

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, parentheses

I'm trying to implement an algorithm from [Algorithmic Toolbox course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithmic-toolbox/home/) that takes an arithmetic expression such as 5+8*4-2 and computes its largest possible value. However, I don't really understand the choice of indices in the last part of the shown algorithm; my implementation fails to compute values using the ones initialized in 2 tables (which are used to store maximized and minimized values of subexpressions).

The evalt function just takes the char, turns it into the operand and computes a product of two digits:

```
def evalt(a, b, op):
    if op == '+':
        return a + b
#and so on
```

MinMax computes the minimum and the maximum values of subexpressions

```
def MinMax(i, j, op, m, M):
    mmin = 10000
    mmax = -10000
    for k in range(i, j-1):
        a = evalt(M[i][k], M[k+1][j], op[k])
        b = evalt(M[i][k], m[k+1][j], op[k])
        c = evalt(m[i][k], M[k+1][j], op[k])
        d = evalt(m[i][k], m[k+1][j], op[k])
        mmin = min(mmin, a, b, c, d)
        mmax = max(mmax, a, b, c, d)
    return(mmin, mmax)
```

And this is the body of the main function

```
def get_maximum_value(dataset):
    op = dataset[1:len(dataset):2]
    d = dataset[0:len(dataset)+1:2]
    n = len(d)
    #iniitializing matrices/tables
    m = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]  #minimized values
    M = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]  #maximized values
    for i in range(n):
        m[i][i] = int(d[i])   #so that the tables will look like
        M[i][i] = int(d[i])   #[[i, 0, 0...], [0, i, 0...], [0, 0, i,...]]
    for s in range(n):   #here's where I get confused
        for i in range(n-s):
            j = i + s
            m[i][j], M[i][j] = MinMax(i,j,op,m,M)
    return M[0][n-1]
```

Comment: What is your question? What is it doing, or not doing, that you don't understand?

Comment: I assume that the MinMax function is faulty somehow as it does not fill the tables m and M correctly.

Comment: You're going to have to explain a little more. I've never taken that class, and I have no idea what your code is trying to do. I see a bunch of zeros, so I suspect it's not doing much, since a+0, a-0, a*0 are not very exciting expressions. Can you explain the intent of your code, what the values should be, something? Maybe give some input and expected output examples?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to bother, here's what had to be improved:

```
for s in range(1,n)
```

in the main function, and

```
for k in range(i, j):
```

in MinMax function. Now it works.

Comment: thank you @Elen ..this helped a lot.   Hope ur NLP research going good

Answer (score 0):

The following change should work.

```
 for s in range(1,n):
    for i in range(0,n-s):
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Also this is a answer to a 2 year old question. Btw, welcome to SO :)